# Rearding spring error : Resource must exist: [class path resource [X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

From past few days, I am getting this error and not able to move forward. 
Please find the error logs and content and help me in finding out the issue. 
My file is physically exits in the location mentioned below.(X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat)

**DWHConfig.xml** :

```
    <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat"/>
    <property name="firstLineIsHeader" value="false"/>
    <property name="recordSeparatorPolicy">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.separator.SimpleRecordSeparatorPolicy" />               </property>
    <property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
    </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="fieldSetMapper">
    <bean class="com.telenor.metro2.conn.ess.batch.DWH.maping.DWHInput_Mapper" />
    </property>
    </bean>
```

**Error** :

```
Jan 9, 2013 2:16:44 PM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing the step: class org.springframework.batch.core.UnexpectedJobExecutionException: Failed to initialize the step
Jan 9, 2013 2:16:45 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=DWHDailyJob]] failed with the following parameters: [{jobName=DWH-Fixed_daily_dap-ess-ora01}{}{}{schedule.date=Wed Jan 09 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013}]
Throwable occurred: org.springframework.batch.core.UnexpectedJobExecutionException: Failed to initialize the step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:170)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.execute(SimpleJob.java:100)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:86)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:81)
    at com.telenor.metro2.conn.ess.batch.launcher.DWHFJobDetail.start(DWHFJobDetail.java:103)
    at com.telenor.metro2.conn.ess.batch.launcher.DWHFJobDetail.execute(DWHFJobDetail.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractBufferedItemReaderItemStream.open(AbstractBufferedItemReaderItemStream.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ItemOrientedStep.open(ItemOrientedStep.java:439)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:167)
    ... 8 more
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource must exist: [class path resource [X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat**]]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:384)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:226)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractBufferedItemReaderItemStream.open(AbstractBufferedItemReaderItemStream.java:154)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you tried with an URL instead of a path? (file:/X:....)

Comment: Can u give some example. I didnt get URL pattern. thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
<property name="resource" value="file:X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat"/>
```

Comment: Superb work and superb quick response :-) It worked. Thanks alot Pradeep

Comment: if this responce solved your problem, you can accept the anwser.

Comment: I am new to this site ..can u tell me how to do that??

Comment: below the up arrow and down vote you can see the right tick mark click on that

Comment: I had the same issue and indeed I was missing the "file:" statement.

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration, Spring is looking for that path inside its classpath (see the Stack Trace). Either load your file as suggested already with

```
<property name="resource" value="file:X:/Content/E/data/FIXED.dat"/>
```

or move the file FIXED.dat into the application classpath and change property to

```
<property name="resource" value="classpath:FIXED.dat"/>
```

Both should work